# MVC.net disable attribute for particular methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an action filter attribute on my BaseController class:

```
<CompressFilter()> _
Public Class BaseController
```

So, this filter is applied to all methods in all controllers of my app.
Is it possible to disable this filter for some particular methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the code for the CompressFilter it is. You can add a second Attribute. For example NoCompressAttribute. In the OnActionExecuting method of the CompressFilter you would look at the ActionDescriptors and if the NoCompressAttribute is applied you would not do the compression.

EDIT: Here is the code

```
 public class CompressFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public bool Compress { get; set; }
        public CompressFilter()
        {
            Compress = true;
        }

        public CompressFilter(bool compress)
        {
            Compress = compress;
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var compressAttribs = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CompressFilter), true);
            foreach (var item in compressAttribs)
            {
                if (!((CompressFilter)item).Compress)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }

            HttpRequestBase request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

            string acceptEncoding = request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptEncoding)) return;

            acceptEncoding = acceptEncoding.ToUpperInvariant();

            HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

            if (acceptEncoding.Contains("GZIP"))
            {
                response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
                response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
            }
            else if (acceptEncoding.Contains("DEFLATE"))
            {
                response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
                response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
            }
        }
    }
```

And then on the action you don't want compression do:

```
[CompressFilter(false)]
public virtual ActionResult Index()
{
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: But.. In that case this code is executed 2 times for every request. Ugly thing. I will use the first option (with NoCompressAttribute). I think it is more logical.

Comment: I agree. That is probably a better idea. This was easier when demostrating the idea as I only needed one class.

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't. When you apply an action attribute to a controller it applies to all actions. You might need to move the action you want to exclude to a different controller.

Comment: Can I inherit controller from BaseController and disable this attribute in it?

Comment: What do you mean by disable an attribute? An attribute is baked in the metadata of the assembly at compile-time.

Answer (score -1):

You can apply FilterAttribute to methods explicitly, instead of applying to all controller. 
Remove attribute from class BaseController, and add it only to methods you need to compress.

Comment: There are hundreds of methods in my app. And only some of them are going to have this attribute disabled

Comment: This is only solution I know, sorry